# javascript ajax help

Tags: javascript, ajax, get

I have the following code.

```
    var d3_ad = 1;

    function displayD3Ad(){
        var query_string = '?d3_ad='+d3_ad;
        query_string += '&location='+escape(location);

    //document.write('<iframe src="index.php'+query_string+'"></iframe>');

    var data = httpRequest('http://localhost/test/index.php','GET',query_string);
    document.write(data);
}

function httpRequest(strURL,type,query) {
    var request = false;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// Mozilla/Safari
        request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { //Internet Explorer
        request= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    request.open(type, strURL + query, true);
    request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
            return request.responseText;
        }
    }

    request.send(null);
}

displayD3Ad();
```

now when it writes out the data it is saying undefined. It seems like it isnt returning the data. I looked in firebug and it completes and shows the response that shoudl be there. Any help is appreciated. I just need to set the data variable so that I can use it later on.

Comment: What is the Content-Type header value in the response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, in JavaScript you'd have to handle the response value in a callback. Which is not ideal for serious application.

There is an extension to the JavaScript language called StratifiedJS. It runs in every browser, and it allows you to get the response value directly (instead of undefined)

You can enable Stratified JavaScript e.g. by including Oni Apollo ( http://onilabs.com/docs ) in your webpage like:

```
<script src="http://code.onilabs.com/latest/oni-apollo.js"></script>
<script type="text/sjs"> your StratifiedJS code here </script>
```

And the your code would look like this:

```
function displayD3Ad(){
  var query_string = '?d3_ad='+d3_ad;
  query_string += '&location='+escape(location);

  var data = require("http").get('http://localhost/test/index.php' + query_string);
  document.write(data);
}
```

This is using the Apollo toolkit so you don't have to write your own HttpRequest function, it's already there in the "http" module.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you've sort-of misunderstood how this mechanism is going to work. When you call your `httpRequest` function, you *initiate* the AJAX transaction, but your function returns pretty much immediately. Only after the server responds will the browser invoke your state change handler, and that return value will basically just get tossed out. I suggest that what you need to do is handle the response text *inside* the state change handler.

Furthermore, it won't work to handle the response with `document.write` because by the time the response returns, your document will be all done. What you'll want to do is have the document include a marker element (a `<span>` or `<div>` or whatever), and then have the handler find that an drop the response text into it.